# How to add a keylistener to JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, keylistener, jpopupmenu

When using a JPopupMenu, pressing escape will result in closing the menu, 
is there a way disable this behaviour or overwrite it? adding a KeyListener to the menu doesn't work.
I already got an item in the JPopupMenu that properly ends the dialog, but closing it by pressing escape will outright stop my program from working.

Comment: Can you post code relating to the `KeyListener` and the error log for when you press escape?

Comment: there are no errors.

and i dont think posting my code will help.
create a jpopupmenu: JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("UnitActionMenu");

how do i change the preset behaviour of pressing the escape key?